# R: lapply function over a list (selecting/sub-setting)

Tags: r

I am having a difficult time to "sub-setting" a list.

For example,

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("5353-66", "55-110-4000","6524-533", "62410-165", "653-520-2410"))
test$x <- as.character(test$x)

strsplit(test$x, "-")
```

strsplit gives me a list as below:

```
[[1]]
[1] "5353" "66"  

[[2]]
[1] "55"   "110"  "4000"

[[3]]
[1] "6524" "533" 

[[4]]
[1] "62410" "165"  

[[5]]
[1] "653"  "520"  "2410"
```

When I run `lapply(strsplit(test$x, "-"), "[[", 1)`, it gives me the first character string from each component of the list as below:

```
[[1]]
[1] "5353"

[[2]]
[1] "55"

[[3]]
[1] "6524"

[[4]]
[1] "62410"

[[5]]
[1] "653"
```

Then... How do I select entire [[1]] and [[2]] and [[3]]... separately?

For example, I want to assign test$y[1] as c("5353", "66") and test$y[2] as c("55" ,  "110" , "4000") and so on.

```
test$y <- lapply(strsplit(test$x, "-"), "[", 1)
```

Above line gave me the same result.

Comment: It can get very messy storying more than one element in a cell in a data.frame. Are you sure you need this? `test$y<-strsplit(test$x, "-")` will assign the list. Use `test$y[[1]]`, `test$y[[2]]`, etc to get the vectors out (note the double brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it can get messy it's also fairly easy to do. You were on the right track but adding an `unlist()` and using `strsplit()` with the `lapply()` will get you what you want.

`test$y <- lapply(1:length(test$x),function(i) unlist(strsplit(test$x[[i]],"-")))`

`test$y[[1]]`

[1] "5353" "66"

Comment: I didn't know one can do a loop in lapply function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the magic of sapply comes in handy --

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("5353-66", "55-110-4000","6524-533", "62410-165", "653-520-2410"))
test$x <- as.character(test$x)

sapply(test$x,strsplit,'-')

$`5353-66`
[1] "5353" "66"  

$`55-110-4000`
[1] "55"   "110"  "4000"

$`6524-533`
[1] "6524" "533" 

$`62410-165`
[1] "62410" "165"  

$`653-520-2410`
[1] "653"  "520"  "2410"
```

What you do with the data from here is up to you. Because your data is ragged, i.e., it will not fit into a rectangular matrix or data frame that needs a fixed number of cells per row, you should keep the data as a list. Data frames in fact are lists, so many of the data frame functions work on them as well.

If you must have a data frame, you can add on NAs for missing cells and then convert it back to a data frame in wide format:

```
      out_list <- sapply(test$x,strsplit,'-')

      max_length <- max(sapply(out_list,length))


      out_list <- lapply(out_list, function(x) {
        if(length(x)<max_length) {
          x <- c(x,rep(NA,times=max_length-length(x)))
        }
        return(x)
      })

      out_data <- as.data.frame(out_list)


      X5353.66 X55.110.4000 X6524.533 X62410.165 X653.520.2410
      1     5353           55      6524      62410           653
      2       66          110       533        165           520
      3     <NA>         4000      <NA>       <NA>          2410
```